# Dynamically obtain a vector along 1 dimension in 'n' dimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy variable that can be 'n' dimensions, for example:

`game_board = np.zeros((4,3,3), dtype=np.int8)`

I want to obtain a vector along the first dimension based on a vector `choose_vector`

`choose_vector = np.array([x,y],dtype=np.int8)`

I know how i can do this statically:

```
game_board[:, x, y] 
# will return [0,0,0,0], the (x,y)th element from 1st dimension
```

but everything I have tried so far doing this using the `choose_vector` has not worked:

```
game_board[:, choose_vector] 
# returns 
[[[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]

print(game_board[choose_vector])
# returns
[[0,0,0]]
```

how do i construct the index for `game_board` given `choose_vector` in order to get the same result as `game_board[:, x, y]`

I'd then like to expand it to any dimensional game board, but I can probably work it out if i know how to do the above :)

Comment: what is `choose_position`? Why don't you do `game_board[:, cv[0], cv[1]]`?

Comment: So in the real implementation, I might not necessarily know the length of choose_position or what the dimensions of game_board are.

Comment: choose_position was a typo, it should be choose_vector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked this out with help from FlashTek. Instead of using np.newaxis, using slice(None) seems to be a drop in replacement for `:`

```
import numpy as np
x,y = 0,0

game_board = np.zeros((4,3,3), dtype=np.int8)
choose_vector = np.array([x, y], dtype=np.uint8)
game_board[[slice(None)] + choose_vector.tolist()]
```

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the cleanest solution, but it doing what you want:

```
import numpy as np
x,y = 0,0

game_board = np.zeros((4,3,3), dtype=np.int8)
choose_vector = np.array([x, y], dtype=np.uint8)
game_board[[np.newaxis] + choose_vector.tolist()]
```

The trick is, that you can "replace" the `:` in your static approach with a `np.newaxis` inside of a python `list`.

Comment: This does not work for me unfortunately. `[np.newaxis] + choose_vector.tolist()` resolves to [None, x, y].

This returns [[0,0,0]] not [0,0,0,0]